# Referenced DLL, in Web API project not reading dll.config nor web.config

Tags: c#, api, dll, web-config, app-config

This has been asked before, but I can't find an answer that works for me.

I have a solution that contains 5 projects, one is a Web API (.net 4.5) and one is a Class Library (.net 4.5). The Web API has a reference to the class/DLL. In the class project, the Settings.settings is utilized to enter values in the App.Config. All the values in the settings are Type string, Scope Application, Access Modifier Internal.

These values are created in the App.Config and look something like this:

```
<applicationSettings>
<xxxxx.Properties.Settings>
  <setting name="setting1" serializeAs="String">
    <value>1</value>
  </setting>
  <setting name="setting2" serializeAs="String">
    <value>abc123</value>
  </setting>....
```

In the class code, the values are read like so:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.setting1;
```

When the package for the Web API is created, it has the .dll, but not the .dll.config file. If I manually copy the .dll.config file, the .dll doesn't read from it. It also doesn't seem to read the ConnectionString fromt he web.config either.

I need the DLL to read either the .dll.config or the Web APIs web.config file. I have tried several solutions posted in stackoverflow, but most seem updated/deprecated and/or throw errors when I tried them.

What is the current and correct approach to this issue, with .net 4.5?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I ended up deleting everything from the Settings.settings eliminating the

```
<applicationSettings>
  <xxxxx.Properties.Settings>...
```

section of the App.Config. Then I just added a regular `<appSettings>` section and calling the value in code with

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["xxxxx"];
```

I read in some posts that this was no longer supported, but it was the method that worked for me.